# retrieve information from a structure with ptrace

Tags: c, struct, ptrace

Here, I explain my problem, I am a beginner on the ptrace function and I would like to succeed in recovering the hard information of a structure.
For example with this command, I will have strace -e trace = fstat ls
a line: fstat (3, {st_mode = ..., st_size = ...}
and I would like to successfully retrieve the contents of the structure (st_mode) and (st_size).
I try this but to no avail:

```
int buffer(unsigned long long addr, pid_t child, size_t size, void *buffer)
{
    size_t byte = 0;
    size_t data;
    unsigned long tmp;

    while (byte < size) {
        tmp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, child, addr + byte);
        if ((size - byte) / sizeof(tmp))
            data = sizeof(tmp);
        else
          data = size % sizeof(tmp);
        memcpy((void *)(buffer + byte), &tmp, data);
        byte += data;
    }
}
```

and in params :

```
struct stat stat_i;
buffer(addr, pid, sizeof(stat_i), &stat_i);
printf("%lu", stat_i.st_size); -> fake value :/
```

Thank'ks !

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html),

> ```
> PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, PTRACE_PEEKDATA
>       Read a word at the address addr in the tracee's memory,
>       returning the word as the result of the ptrace() call.  Linux
>       does not have separate text and data address spaces, so these
>       two requests are currently equivalent.  (data is ignored; but
>       see NOTES.)
> ```

Thus you must understand that `tmp` would hold the actually value that was read.

Your checks are wrong - you should set `errno = 0` before the call and then check if it has changed. If it has - you've got an error. If it hasn't - you can be assured that `tmp` has the word from the remote process.

Try something like this:

```
int buffer(unsigned long long addr, pid_t child, size_t size, void *buffer)
{
    size_t byte = 0;
    size_t data;
    unsigned long tmp;

    // support for word aligned sizes only
    if (size % sizeof(long) != 0)
        return -1;

    long * buffer_int = (long*) buffer;

    while (byte < size) {
        errno = 0;
        tmp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, child, addr + byte);
        if (errno)
            return -1;
        buffer_int[byte / sizeof(long)] = tmp;

        byte += sizeof(long);
    }
}
```